# Lost RAID disk 1, unable to recover

Tags: boot, grub2, raid, disk, mdadm

So,

Raid 1 with two disks, both disks started to give warnings (but we all know this company types, they don't let you do stuff until the horse has run a few miles out of the barn and the whole building is on fire).

Disk 1 died and the raid marked it as _. I put the new disk (after a few, errr, weeks) and started syncing, everything seemed ok but I didn't knew I was going to lose Grub.

Next boot, the system couldn't boot properly and it was to a point where I couldn't move Grub from sda to sdb; now the disk has died (as in the motor doesn't even start) and I don't know how to follow.

Disk 2 has been synced with the raid; if I boot with a live CD and do an "assemble scan" it finds the disk is part of a Raid but as a spare.

Is there any way at all to rebuild grub and remount that disk? I am grasping at straws here...

Thank you all.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair - or do it manually, mounting the appropriate drives in a live cd, chroot to your system and reinstall grub manually.

Comment: @vidarlo This is more of an answer than a comment. Consider expanding the comment to a full answer.

Comment: @user68186 feel free to do so - I don't have time right now for writing an extended answer, but commented in the hope that those comments would help :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that MBR is not part of the RAID setup. You need to reinstall Grub on the drive.

Step one is to boot with a Ubuntu Live medium, either from CD or USB. Open a terminal, and become root using `sudo -i`.

Assemble the array, as you stated in the question. This will give you some devices in `/dev/md`. Mount the one with your root file system as `/mnt/`, running the commant `mount /dev/md/device /mnt`.

If you have a separate boot partition, for instance `/dev/sda1`, you will have to mount this at `/mnt/boot`

Next, you will have to mount the syfs, dev and procfs to /mnt/sys, /mnt/dev and /proc respectively:

```
mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount -o bind /proc /mnt/proc
```

Now you should be able to chroot to /mnt:

```
chroot /mnt
```

This should give you a new bash prompt, from the root file system. If you're unsure if you have a seperate boot partition, please do a `grep "/boot" /etc/fstab` to check. If you have, mount it.

Next step is to reinstall grub.

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

This assumes that sda is the device you want to reinstall grub to - please check this.

Unless you get any error messages, this is what is needed to reinstall grub. The array will run in degraded mode.

Comment: Thanks for that set of instructions. The first one (mount) already failed, can't read superblock...

Comment: You know what. I give up... stupid Linux Raids; you lose a disk and lose everything, useless...

Comment: Try checking the file system on the disk. That said - RAID is not backup, it's a mean for getting improved uptime.